# Meteor Methods doesn't update database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, meteor

I tried this function nothing is happening

```
 const pers = Person.findOne({_id:pers._id});
      console.log(pers._id) // This is working 
 PersParametersToUpdate[pers_id].paramsHash) {

  if (pers && pers.paramsHash != paramsHash) {

  Person.update(pers_id, {
          $set: {
            "state.label": "connected",
            name: name,
            email: version,
            adress: hardware,
paramsHash: paramsHash
          }
        });
```

I think my problem is coming from my update method, because i can match the id. but i can't update my database

Comment: Can you complete and properly format the example code, please? Some variables are not defined and the code has faulty syntax. Otherwise it is hard to spot the source of the error.

Comment: Your update function seems ok. Do you enter the if statement ? Do you have a Schema attached to the Person Collection ? Using debug mode of SimpleSchema can sometimes help